# Mismatched scores on the tag topusers page - `Last 30 Days` consistently higher than `All Time`

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tag-score

I've been concentrating on improving my Ionic 4 knowledge recently so my first stop has been the [ionic4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ionic4) tag each day.

I've noticed that my score is consistently off by one:

[image: Mismatched scores]

But it's either the wrong way around or a bug.

The graphic shows that my `last 30 days` score is 26 and my `all time` is 25.

I thought it was just a caching issue or similar but it has stayed consistent as my score has gone up, the `last 30 days` has always stayed 1 ahead of my `all time`.

Seems like there could be some subtle bug in how these are calculated?

Comment: `last 30 days` is hardly a good measure of `all time` in any case. Wait a week and your all time score will be off by more than 1 with respect to your 30 day score. Anyhow, you could've spotted the difference by the fact that the all time record also shows an answer extra wrt to the last 30 days

Comment: Thanks, I have only been "active" on the ionic 4 tag within the last 30 days so that's it seemed like it should add up. I understand now that it was the -1 on a single question I answered a while ago.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The stats looks correct. **At the time of your screenshot** (*since you've just posted another answer*),

- You had 63 undeleted answers for questions with [ionic4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ionic4) tag in the [past 30 days](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3A156388%20%5Bionic4%5D%20is%3Aanswer%20created%3A30d..)
- [You have 64 undeleted all-time answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3A156388+%5Bionic4%5D+is%3Aanswer) for questions with [ionic4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ionic4) tag

  - Your answer in Feb 2019 https://stackoverflow.com/a/54814522, has a post score of **-1**, so the all-time score is 1 less.

Tag scores and tag leaderboards are recalculated and cached daily at UTC 03:00.

Comment: thank you, I have learned something today :D